# Sails/ Waterline: Ids of associations in query result not accessible without populate

Tags: mongodb, ember.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I am to a fair degree familiar with Sails and Waterline.

**Situation:**

- We have a Model *Playlist* with a many-to-many association to the Model *Song* on sails-mongo.
- When we query for all playlists, we do not want to sideload all associated songs, **we just need the ids** of the associated songs so that we can load them lazily later.
- When we do a populate (with Ember blueprints: populateEach()) we of course get the ids, but it takes around 1s for loading all the Playlists.
- Without populate it is **just around 50ms**.

**Complication:**

- After getting the results with `query.exec` WITHOUT populate, the ids of the associated songs are not included and not sent back to the requester.
- But I can log the ids of associated records to the console via iterating over `Object.keys(matchingRecord)`.
- I can set them to a new property of the matchingRecord, all without populating.
- However, **I cannot explicitly set them to their property name**.
- Using the original property name is required for the interaction with the Ember frontend.
- I tried to mess around with `Object.defineProperty` - no success. I guess the set/get functions are overwritten to prevent that.

**Questions:**

- How can I make those id arrays of visible/prevent that they are hidden/removed?
- Are there any other ideas from your side to maneuver around this issue?

Thank you,
Manuel

Comment: I can stringify and parse every property and push them to a new array and put that to the response. But this is neither elegant nor efficient.